# Высота(ширина) трансформированного input type date берется за ширину ячейки в таблице. Как сузить ширину ячейки?

Tags: javascript, html5, table, transform

[image: Скрин.]ширина td должна быть равна ширине(высота)Input. Как это реализовать? Это что то похожее на электронный журнал

Answer (score -1):

попробуйте так

```
'use strict';
let table = document.body.querySelector('table'); //я предполагаю, что таблица одна,
//сами можете выбрать подходящий селектор

let input = document.body.querySelector('input'); //то же самое

table.rows[0].cells[2].style.width = getComputedStyle(input).height;
```